# Pra que serve o padding do container do Bootstrap?

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Pra que serve o `padding` do `container` do Bootstrap se a `row` tem um `margin` negativo que cancela esse `padding`? Se eu quiser que toda a minha pagina tenha um `padding` pra que ela não fique grudada na borda como eu faço?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja que: *(independente se é Bootstrap 3 ou Bootstrap 4)*

**`Container:`** O contêiner funciona dessa maneira para que as bordas do contêiner possam ter esse `padding` virtual de 15px ao redor do conteúdo, mas não exigir que a tag `body` tenha um `padding` de 15px. Esta foi uma alteração no RC1 do Bootstrap 3. Caso contrário, o corpo inteiro teria um `padding` de 15px, isso faria que mesmo as `divs` sem as classes de Bootstrap não ocupem 100% da largura do `body`

**`Rows:`** As `rows` têm margem negativa igual ao preenchimento dos contêineres para que também toquem a borda do contêiner, a margem negativa sobrepondo o `padding` do `container`. Isso permite que a `row` não seja empurrada para dentro pelo `padding` do contêiner.

**`Cols`**: as `cols-` também têm o `padding` de 15px, para que elas finalmente mantenham seu conteúdo de 15px longe da borda do container / browser / viewport, além de fornecer a medianiz de 15px + 15px entre as colunas. É assim, isso serve para criar uma consistência entre os espaçamentos das colunas, não importando se a coluna é a primeira ou a última. Agora, sempre vai haver 15px de espaçamento entre as colunas.

Agora vamos analisar essas imagens

O `container` tem dois propósitos:

1. Fornecer as restrições de largura em larguras responsivas. Quando os
   tamanhos responsivos mudam, é o contêiner que muda. Linhas e colunas
   são todas baseadas em porcentagem, de modo que não precisam ser
   alteradas.
2. Fornecer `padding` para que o conteúdo não toque na borda do
   navegador. Isso é 15px em cada lado, como visto em rosa na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você nunca deve usar um `container` dentro de outro!

As `rows` também têm um aspecto único de ter 15px de margem negativa em cada lado, como visto em azul na imagem abaixo. O `div` que compõe a `row` normalmente seria restrito dentro do preenchimento dos contêineres, tocando as bordas da área rosa, mas não além dela. As margens negativas de 15px empurram a linha para fora sobre o `padding` de 15px dos `containers`.

Nunca use uma linha fora de um contêiner, não vai funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As colunas agora têm padding de 15px, visto em amarelo. Esse preenchimento significa que as colunas realmente tocam a borda da linha, que por sua vez toca a borda do contêiner, pois a linha tem a margem negativa e o contêiner tem o padding positivo. Mas, o preenchimento na coluna empurra qualquer coisa dentro da coluna para onde ela precisa estar, e também fornece um espaçamento entre elas de 30px.

Nunca use uma coluna fora de uma linha, não vai funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Fonte:*** http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

**Resumidamente:**

As `cols` precisam de um `padding` para não deixar o conteúdo ir até as margens, e para manter um espaçamento entre um coluna e outra. A `row` precisa da margem para equalizar o `padding` do `container` não deixando o conteúdo encostar na janela do browser e para evitar que só a primeira e a última coluna tenham espaços a esquerda e a direita. Então com esse conjunto de `padding` e `margins` vc consegue uma consistência nos espaçamentos do grid e ainda pode ter `divs` que alcancem até a borda da janela do browser já que vc não precisa de `padding` no `body`